# Using np package to publish to npm or yarn

Tags: npm, publish, yarnpkg, np

I'm trying to use [np](https://github.com/sindresorhus/np) to publish a package to `npm`. Everything seems to be going fine until it hits the bumping the version number. I can't figure out what is going wrong.

```
  ✔ Prerequisite check
  ✔ Git
  ✔ Cleanup
  ✔ Installing dependencies using npm
  ✔ Running tests using npm
  ✖ Bumping version using npm
    → v1.0.3
    Publishing package using npm
    Pushing tags

✖ Command failed: npm version 1.0.3
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: git tag v1.0.3 -sm 1.0.3
npm ERR! error: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory
npm ERR! error: gpg failed to sign the data
npm ERR! error: unable to sign the tag
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ds/.npm/_logs/2019-06-28T13_11_44_469Z-debug.log

v1.0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had set `version-sign-git-tag` to `true`, and since I have no `gpg` installed on my machine, the signing of the tags was failing. Setting the flag to `false` solved the issue. Not the best approach I guess, but the quickest.